# Visualizing a couple of Shield UI ASP.NET MVC charts on a single page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, shieldui

I am new to Shield UI ASP.NET MVC charts I seems to have come across a quite strange problem. I am using two charts on a page and took code from online tutorial, but am stuck and cannot continue. When both of them are present:

```
@(Html.ShieldChart()
.Name("chart")
.AxisX(axisX => axisX.Title(title => title.Text("Speed of Wind")))
.AxisY(axisY => axisY.Title(title => title.Text("RainFall Quantities")))
.PrimaryHeader(header => header.Text("Weather - Wind/Precipitation Values"))
.Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip.AxisMarkers(axisMarkers => axisMarkers
    .Enabled(true)
    .Mode(Shield.Mvc.UI.Chart.TooltipAxisMarkerMode.XY)
    .Width(1)
    .ZIndex(3)))
.ChartLegend(chartLegend => chartLegend
    .Align(Shield.Mvc.UI.Chart.Align.Right)
    .VerticalAlign(Shield.Mvc.UI.Chart.VerticalAlign.Top)
    .RenderDirection(Shield.Mvc.UI.Chart.Direction.Vertical))
.DataSeries(dataSeries => dataSeries.Scatter()
    .CollectionAlias("January 2008")
 …..
)

 @(Html.ShieldChart()
.Name("chart")
.Export(false)
.PrimaryHeader(header => header.Text("Browsers Popularity amongst Users"))
.ChartLegend(legend=>legend.Enabled(true))
.SeriesSettings(setting=>setting.Pie(pie=>pie
    .EnablePointSelection(true)))
.Tooltip(tooltip=>tooltip.CustomPointText("{point.collectionAlias}: {point.y}"))        
.DataSeries(dataSeries => dataSeries.Pie()
    .CollectionAlias("Usage")
  …..
 )
```

There is nothing to be seen on page. When I remove any of them the other displays correctly. What could the problem be? Do I need to add additional  elements to make up containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no any additional elements needed. What the problem is, that there is a conflict between the charts names. Probably you haven’t  noticed, that both of your charts have the same name:

.Name("chart")

Basically divs with same IDs would show up on a page and just hinder a JS script accessing them, here the problem results in not showing the charts.
You may change the names like

```
.Name("chartA") 

and 

.Name("chartB")
```

for instance and the problem must be solved.